# Excel forcing a macro command

Tags: vba, excel

I made a workbook in which some sheets are needed to be protected from watching since a lot of people are going to enter this sheet and I would like to have more sensative information in it which will not be available for all.
To do so I googled and found out the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim MySheets As String, Response As String
MySheet = "Sheet1"
If ActiveSheet.Name = MySheet Then
ActiveSheet.Visible = False
    Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")
        If Response = "MyPass" Then
            Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets(MySheet).Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
End If
Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
End Sub
```

which works perfectly for my needs but there is a problem.
The problem is as following, for it to work I need to force the user to enable macro commands and if you were to save the file then you'd have to save it as an macro-enabled workbook which is not something I trust my users to do.
My question is: Can I make so that without enabling the macro command you are unable to open the sheet without accepting the macros and you are unable to save as a normal Excel workbook?

Comment: `Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True` you're making your sheet visible in all cases? what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: What it does is that when ever someone tries to enter the sheet- the tab   then it requests them of a password.   
If this password does not match the password which I wrote "MyPass" in this case then it doesn't allow them access.

Comment: This is what I dont understand, because **after** the `If` and before leaving the sub, you're doing again `Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True`. This statement is executed whatever password the users types in, did I miss something??

Comment: The level of security your will achieve with that is not really that good. Anyway, are are ways to force your users to activate macros. You could, for example. hide all sheets except one that says "enable macros" and protect the workbook from changes. Then put some code in the "Workbook.Open" Sub that shows the Sheets.

Comment: I don't need it to be really that good I need users to not to accidently screw things up.
That example is actually what I am currently trying to do, Do you have a good recommendation of what a good code for that might look like? The one I am currently using:[http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/forcing-your-clients-to-enable-excel-macros/] which is giving me some problems and doesn't always work.

Comment: My spesific problem with this line of code that it doesn't always set you off to the starting page. Sometimes it does sometimes it doesn't and I don't really know why. It could be because I deleted the ActiveWorkbook.Save line because its caused issues with users who just typed something down or deleted something and tried to leave the document without saving.

Comment: @A.S.H The reason for that line is because if they don't put the correct password it hides the page and then its unaccsessable

Comment: If you want it to **hide** the page when they don't enter the password, you need to have it structured like `If Response = "MyPass" Then Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True \\ Else Sheets(MySheet).Visible =` **`False`**

Comment: The simplest answer here is to have 2 workbooks, one of which is password protected for read access and contains the sensitive information. If you have *any* VBA code in a workbook, it **must** be saved as a `.xlsm` macro-enabled workbook.

Comment: Suppose for instance that we can prevent saving the WB in `.xlsx` format. How can we prevent a user who can see the sensitive data to just *Copy/Paste* it in an xlsx file? I'm afraid that what you're looking for is kind of cheating yourself. Either the data is sensitive or it is not; if it is, manage it in a different, more *robust* way. Sorry for saying that but it really looks to me like a X-Y problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer here is password-protecting that worksheet using excel's built in functionality: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/protect-sheet.html

EDIT: protecting sheet only prevents edits, suggested new method of hiding detailed here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/hide-excel-sheets-really-hide-them/

Comment: This built in protect sheet won't work for me because you can still view the contents of a protected sheet.

I need someone to not be able to go in

Comment: you are right. How about this sneaky trick? http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/hide-excel-sheets-really-hide-them/

Comment: if I turn it into very hidden how do I then accsess it? I mean even the hyperlinks won't redirect me to it. Not to mention that the problem wasn't that I didn't want them not to write said page but not view the pages I want them not to be able to view